# Working with WolframCloud

Tags: notebooks, wolfram-cloud, editing

I'm using WolframCloud from my smartphone and I'm having trouble to select all the cells of my notebook to delete them.

There is a command that selects all the cells in a notebook?

I tried using the `SelectAll` command, but did not get the expected result. I'm certainly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Notebook]` returns `$Failed` you can use:

```
NotebookDelete @ Cells[]
```